# How to remove the “Powered by Cognito Forms” link at bottom

Tags: cognito-forms

Anyway to remove the “Powered by Cognito Forms” link at the bottom? Sometimes people will accidentally hit that instead of submit and they lose the form and have to fill it out all over again.

Answer (score 6):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.

To provide context to this question, you are asking is it possible to remove the link to Cognito Forms that appears below the form when you send out a link to the form.  This is what this looks like:

[image]

So the answer is yes and no, so I will explain both.

**Yes**, if you embed your form on your own website the Powered by Cognito Forms link, along with the Report Abuse and Terms of Services links, will not appear.  This is the immediate and best answer to your question.

**No**, you cannot remove these links at the bottom when the form is actually displayed on https://www.cognitoforms.com.  The reason for this is we must alert the user filling out the form that Cognito Forms is hosting the form but is not responsible for the content.  This is our obligation, along with the opportunity for users to report abuse.  We tried to clearly separate these links from the rest of the form, but still need them to appear and be close enough to be effective.  Having said this, I will make the Powered by Cognito Forms link open in a new window (like the other two already do), which should alleviate the issue you reported.

Thanks for alerting us of this issue!

Comment: Here is a site with an embedded Cognito form, at the bottom of which is the Powered by Cognito Forms link, along with the Report Abuse and Terms of Services links: http://www.jazmyadesign.us/#!website-design-questionnaire/cih0

Comment: In this case they are using an iframe to embed the direct form link.  Our embed option definitely does not include any Cognito branding or links.

Answer (score 0):

With our May 2016 release of [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), we have completely removed branding for all paid plans.  This change includes both public and embedded forms, and all email notifications and confirmations.

Comment: I suggest editing your previous answer would be better.

Comment: Since this represents a completely different answer, would it better to edit the original answer and completely replace the answer with a new answer or add this as an EDIT: at the top and leave the original answer?